# Converting Mongo db result to JSON

Tags: php, json, mongodb, phalcon

I am using Phalcon framework with MongoDB database, this project is a restful project and i need json output from each controller, i have a collection in MongoDB database and when i reading it and converting to json, i am getting a result like below :

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "count": 1
    },
    "records": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5659c36e9dd39ed34024f9a1"
        },
        "name": "main",
        "cities": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$id": "5659c36e9dd39ed34024f9a2"
                },
                "name": "child1"
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$id": "5659c36e9dd39ed34024f9bd"
                },
                "name": "child2"
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$id": "5659c36e9dd39ed34024f9be"
                },
                "name": "child2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And as you can see , we have a field with `"$id"` name, i think it is not good, because i am using this result in mobile apps, and it will case a problem for me when i want to parse this `json` to `POJO` classes.
I know why we have "$id" in output, but i don't know how can i replace it, i don't want to use `str_replace` or `foreach` syntax, i believe `phalcon` or `mongodb` model in Phalcon, should have a solution for it.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate recursively through the object and unset the property

Comment: I guess something like that:

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like that:
If we assume that the object you get from the db is $result:

```
// Object from db
$result;

// Get only records
$records = $result->records;

// Unset undesired properties recursively
$this->iterateRecursively($records);

public function iterateRecursively($object, $properties = ['_id'])
{
    foreach ($object as $key => $value){

         // Unset undesired properties
         foreach ($properties as $property){
              if ($key === $property){
                 unset($object->{$property});
             }
         }

         // Dig deeper into object
         if (is_object($value)){
             $this->iterateRecursively($value);
         }
    }
}
```